# Why does floor() round up in dart?

Tags: dart, math, floor

```
-3.6.floorToDouble()
```

I'd expect this to return -4, because floor() rounds towards negative infinty, but it actually returns -3. It basically acts like truncate(). Is this a bug in the dart sdk or implemented on purpose?

Comment: The docs say it *"Returns the greatest integer double value no greater than this."* so at least, -3 is not the specified behaviour for an input of -3.6.

Comment: @kaya3 Not using dart but that is definition of `ceil` in all environments I encounter and work with ... so the dart is changing the meaning of standard math functions ?! OMG ...

Comment: ceil would round up for positive numbers. But floor rounds down on positve and "up" in negative.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions -2.7 would get floored to -3 according to wikipedia

Comment: i opened a bug at the dart sdk repo: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45963

Comment: alright, (-3.6).floorToDouble() this does actually return -4. But i still have no clue what happens when i omit the brackets

Comment: Uh, without parentheses it's `-(3.6.floor())` which is `-3`.

Comment: Note that the ambiguity in operator precedence should rarely be a problem in practice since the ambiguity is primarily with numeric literals, and people generally use named constants or variables instead of magic numbers.

Comment: So, it was an error of precedential significance? (/me ducks)

Answer (score 5):

It's a parsing artifact.

The expression `-3.6.floorToDouble()` means `-(3.6.floorToDouble())` because the postfix `.` binds stronger than the prefix `-`.

You need to parenthesize negative number literals when you *immediately* call methods on them. That's a remarkably rare thing to do in real programs — the methods on numbers are generally ones where you can predict the result and just write that as a literal instead.